# HTACCESS rewrite URL that contains percent signs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I generate URLs using mcrypt in PHP and the results often contain percent signs like this: https://example.com/J6CVxO7lzS0KSimTgmpY4LcqDflQUWkmihBxBrXh%2FdnP8W8vUfFWbq3faAURi098

The problem is that HTACCESS doesn't like the percent sign so none of my rewrites match the URI; I have tried "\w", "." and [a-zA-z0-9\%]).

Is there a way to take everything after the domain name and redirect to index.php?id={EVERYTHING AFTER "example.com/"}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the issue that in the above example %2F decodes to a slash '/'? Maybe try to just match the entire uri with some like:

^([^.}+)$

Comment: Yes, the %2F is the problem and there are a number of others like %2B.  The "^." only matches characters and doesn't include %.  I tried the B flag but that didn't help anything.  In the end I decided to use str_replace to turn % into _ and then I just perform the opposite (_ to %) before decrypting.